# SSIS: Precedence Constraint not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Referring to the below snapshot, I am trying to use "Logical AND All constraint must be evaluated to true". In Expression, I am trying to equate Variable value with the current date and when checking it on evaluation expression it shows true when the condition is matching but still while running the package it doesn't move to the next step.

Expression used:

```
@[User::LastUpdated] == (DT_DBDATE) GETDATE()
```

Please help on this issue. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then either the prior step didn't succeed or  `@[User::LastUpdated] == (DT_DBDATE) GETDATE()` is not true. We don't know which, you'll need to debug that as we can't run your package.

Answer (score 0):

The second screenshot shows that the Script Task is executed successfully which means that the first constraint is met. You should make sure that the `@[User::LastUpdated]` date value is equal to `(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE()`.

*Hint: Make sure that the `@[User::LastUpdated]` date value does not include the time part. You can use the following expression to avoid the time part problem:*

```
(DT_DBDATE)@[User::LastUpdated] == (DT_DBDATE)GETDATE()
```